# Using DoctrineModule UniqueObject validator annotation in ZF3 app?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-form, zf3

I am trying to use the DoctrineModule's `UniqueObject` validator annotation in an entity with `Zend\Form` (ZF3) but am unable to do so.

Annotation in entity:

```
 * @Annotation\Validator({"name":"DoctrineModule\Validator\UniqueObject"})
```

Controller method that uses entity:

```
public function saveAction()
{   
    $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
    $user = $this->em->getRepository(User::class)->find($id);        
    $builder = new AnnotationBuilder();
    ...
```

Module.php:

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return [
        'factories' => [
            'DoctrineModule\Validator\UniqueObject' => function ($serviceManager) {
                $uniqueObject = new DoctrineModule\Validator\UniqueObject(array(
                    'fields' => 'username',
                    'object_repository' => $serviceManager->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager')->getRepository('Application\Entity\User'),
                    'object_manager' => $serviceManager->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager'),
                ));
                return $uniqueObject;
            },
        ],
    ];
}
```

Error seen:

```
[Catchable fatal error] Argument 1 passed to DoctrineModule\Validator\UniqueObject::__construct() must be of the type array, none given, called in /var/www/jade/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/Factory/InvokableFactory.php on line 32 and defined
[0] file:///var/www/jade/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/src/DoctrineModule/Validator/UniqueObject.php.DoctrineModule\Validator\UniqueObject->__construct:66
[1] file:///var/www/jade/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/Factory/InvokableFactory.php.Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory->__invoke:32
[2] file:///var/www/jade/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php.Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate:747
[3] file:///var/www/jade/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php.Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get:195
[4] file:///var/www/jade/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/AbstractPluginManager.php.Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager->get:143
[5] file:///var/www/jade/vendor/zendframework/zend-validator/src/ValidatorChain.php.Zend\Validator\ValidatorChain->plugin:97
[6] file:///var/www/jade/vendor/zendframework/zend-validator/src/ValidatorChain.php.Zend\Validator\ValidatorChain->attachByName:194
[7] file:///var/www/jade/vendor/zendframework/zend-inputfilter/src/Factory.php.Zend\InputFilter\Factory->populateValidators:428
[8] file:///var/www/jade/vendor/zendframework/zend-inputfilter/src/Factory.php.Zend\InputFilter\Factory->createInput:267
[9] file:///var/www/jade/vendor/zendframework/zend-inputfilter/src/Factory.php.Zend\InputFilter\Factory->createInputFilter:357
[10] file:///var/www/jade/vendor/zendframework/zend-form/src/Factory.php.Zend\Form\Factory->prepareAndInjectInputFilter:545
[11] file:///var/www/jade/vendor/zendframework/zend-form/src/Factory.php.Zend\Form\Factory->configureForm:284
[12] file:///var/www/jade/vendor/zendframework/zend-form/src/Factory.php.Zend\Form\Factory->create:114
[13] file:///var/www/jade/vendor/zendframework/zend-form/src/Factory.php.Zend\Form\Factory->createForm:177
[14] file:///var/www/jade/vendor/zendframework/zend-form/src/Annotation/AnnotationBuilder.php.Zend\Form\Annotation\AnnotationBuilder->createForm:246
[15] file:///var/www/jade/module/Application/src/Controller/UserController.php.Application\Controller\UserController->saveAction:132
[16] file:///var/www/jade/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractActionController.php.Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch:78
[17] file:///var/www/jade/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php.Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners:271
[18] file:///var/www/jade/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php.Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil:151
[19] file:///var/www/jade/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractController.php.Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch:105
[20] file:///var/www/jade/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/DispatchListener.php.Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch:119
[21] file:///var/www/jade/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php.Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners:271
[22] file:///var/www/jade/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php.Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil:151
[23] file:///var/www/jade/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php.Zend\Mvc\Application->run:332
[24] file:///var/www/jade/public/index.php.include:40
[25] file:///var/www/jade/index.php.{main}:2
```

Based on discussion in the thread DoctrineModule/issues/585, I injected the `FormElementManager` into the constructor of the `UserController` via factory and attached it from there to the `AnnotationBuilder`:

```
public function __construct(EntityManager $em, \Zend\Form\FormElementManager $fem)
{
    $this->em = $em;
    $this->fem = $fem;
    ...
}


public function saveAction() {
    ...
    $builder->setFormFactory(new \Zend\Form\Factory($this->fem));
    ...
}
```

However this simply ended up back at the original error/stack trace. Interestingly, when I dump `$this->fem`, I do see the UniqueObject validator in the dump output so not clear what's going wrong. I'd appreciate any help or suggestions to get the `UniqueObject` annotation recognized by the `AnnotationBuilder`.

Some links I referred to when researching this:

https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/issues/289
http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.php.zend.framework.general/41719

Answer (score 0):

Can try:

```
<?php
/**
 * Zend Framework Application.
 */

namespace Fork\DoctrineModule\Validator\Factory;

use DoctrineModule\Validator\UniqueObject;

use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;

/**
 * UniqueObjectFactory factory.
 *
 * Creates an instance of UniqueObject.
 *
 * @package Blog\Repository\Factory
 * @link    https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/validator.md
 * @link    https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/src/DoctrineModule/Validator/UniqueObject.php
 */
class UniqueObjectFactory implements FactoryInterface
{

    /**
     * Factory for UniqueObject.
     *
     * @param  ContainerInterface $container
     * @param  string $requestedName
     * @param  array $options
     * @return UniqueObject
     */
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        // Get services.
        $entityManager = $container->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');

        // If 'object_repository' string, try find repository in EntityManager.
        // Sets ObjectManager.
        if (is_string($options['object_repository'])) {
            $options['object_manager']    = $entityManager;
            $options['object_repository'] = $entityManager->getRepository($options['object_repository']);
        }

        return new UniqueObject($options);
    }

}
```

and in module

```
<?php
/**
 * Zend Framework Application.
 */

namespace Fork\DoctrineModule;

/**
 * Configuration for Fork\DoctrineModule module.
 *
 * Changes and extends configuration of DoctrineModule module.
 *
 * @link https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/config/module.config.php
 * @link https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/src/DoctrineModule/Module.php
 */
return [
    /**
     * Configurations for Zend Framework services and components.
     */
    'validators' => [
        'factories' => [
            Validator\UniqueObject::class => Validator\Factory\UniqueObjectFactory::class,
        ],
        'aliases' => [
            'UniqueObject' => Validator\UniqueObject::class,
        ],
    ],
];
```

and in annotation

```
* @Annotation\Validator({
*    'name': 'UniqueObject',
*    'break_chain_on_failure': 'true',
*    'options': {
*        'object_repository': 'Application\Entity\User', // you have User::class
*        'fields': {'bla-bla-bla'},          // ??? - what you have?
*        'messages': {
*            'objectFound' => "bla-bla-bla"
*       },
*    }, 
* })
```

Comment: Thanks @novrm. I tried this but the validator does not seem to be located. I see this error:

`A plugin by the name "UniqueObject" was not found in the plugin manager Zend\Validator\ValidatorPluginManager
#0 /var/www/jade/vendor/zendframework/zend-validator/src/ValidatorChain.php(97): Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager->get('UniqueObject', Array)
#1 /var/www/jade/vendor/zendframework/zend-validator/src/ValidatorChain.php(194): Zend\Validator\ValidatorChain->plugin('UniqueObject', Array)`

Comment: Seems like this is a common problem: [https://github.com/zendframework/zend-validator/issues/40](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-validator/issues/40)